# Can I make all checkboxes checked and unchecked do the same thing?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

Need some help, each checkbox is supposed to only allow that id to be displayed.

If all checkboxes are checked all ids are displayed.

Is there a way to make it so that when all checkboxes are Unchecked all ids are displayed as well?

```
function numbercheck()
{
var vis = (form1.one.checked) ? "block" : "none"; 
document.getElementById("one").style.display = vis;

var vis = (form1.two.checked) ? "block" : "none"; 
document.getElementById("two").style.display = vis;

var vis = (form1.three.checked) ? "block" : "none"; 
document.getElementById("three").style.display = vis;

}

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">

<input type="checkbox" name="one" onclick="numbercheck();" tabindex="one" />
one<br/>
<input name="two" onclick="numbercheck();" type="checkbox" value="two" />
two<br/>
<input name="three" onclick="numbercheck();" type="checkbox" value="three" />
three
</form>
```

Comment: `getElementById` only works when your element have IDs.

Comment: Why dont you do one more if in `numbercheck` setting them visible when they are all unchecked? Or you can just make a big statement like `checked OR (1 unchecked AND 2 unchecked AND 3 unchecked)`.

Comment: when I try that nothing seems to work.  I'm pretty novice.

Comment: not sure where my elements went, that's weird.  They were supposed to be after the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be cleaned up and done simpler I'm sure, but this should do what you want.

```
function numbercheck()
{
var vis = (form1.one.checked) ? "block" : "none"; 
document.getElementById("one").style.display = vis;

var vis = (form1.two.checked) ? "block" : "none"; 
document.getElementById("two").style.display = vis;

var vis = (form1.three.checked) ? "block" : "none"; 
document.getElementById("three").style.display = vis;

if (!form1.one.checked && !form1.two.checked && !form1.three.checked)
{
    document.getElementById("one").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("two").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("three").style.display = "block";
}

}
```